# Using C#, is it possible to make System.Data.OleDb handle special characters?

Tags: c#, oracle

I have an existing C# project that reads a text file and loads it into an Oracle DB using  System.Data.OleDb as provider.  Problem is that if the file has upper ascii characters (e.g. ÀÑÓ, non-breaking space) it always generates an error when it tries to load it into Oracle:

Error is: *OLEDBConnection Command Parameter data value could not be converted for reasons other than sign mismatch or data overflow*.

Our Oracle can accept upper ascii characters (insert via SQL*PLUS works fine), it is System.Data.OleDb that is having issue.

Anyone know if there is a setting to change this?  Can't believe that that only accepts A-Z-0-9.  Looked thru a ll documentation but couldn't find anything.

If it can't, how do you let OLEDB know to escape the character.  Tired putting \ in the file before special characters, but it still errors with same message.

Comment: Quick note: these aren't "upper ASCII" characters - ASCII doesn't contain any accented characters... it's a simple 7-bit encoding.

Comment: Have you tried using the inbuilt `System.Data.OracleClient` classes, or even the official ODP.NET (Oracle ADO.NET Provider), instead of the OLEDB ADO.NET provider?

Comment: What does your connection string look like?

Comment: It is not possible to change provider to something else at this time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to use HEX conversions. For example %c4 is Ä.

Try that and let me know if that works. Here are the conversion functions you can use.

```
internal String convertAsciiTextToHex(String asciiText)
{
StringBuilder sBuffer = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < asciiText.Length; i++)
{
    sBuffer.Append(Convert.ToInt32(asciiText[i]).ToString("x"));
}
return sBuffer.ToString().ToUpper();
}

internal String convertHexToAsciiText(String hexString)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

 for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2)
 {
   string hs = hexString.Substring(i, 2);
   sb.Append(Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToUInt32(hs, 16)));
 }
    String ascii = sb.ToString();
    return ascii;
}
```

Comment: I don't want the characters converted, I want to be able to read an Ñ from the file and store it in Oracle via OLEDB.  Oracle can store them and the files provide them.  These are spanish names and converting an Ñ to something else make it a different name.

Comment: You're only converting them to hexadecimal, you're not changing the actual value. I'm curious to see if it'd encode them properly in your Oracle DB.

Comment: It stores the hex value in the database since i am using a standard insert into a varchar2 column.  converting an Ñ to hex will store the hex value.  I would need to use special oracle function to do a hex conversion back to ascii

Comment: varchar2? Don't you want nvarchar2?

Answer (score 3):

Usually this is possible without any problem... since you don't provide much detail only some general pointers:

- Database Charset should be set to AL32UTF8
  you can check this by executing `SELECT parameter, value FROM nls_database_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';`
- Client Charset should be set to AL32UTF8
  see for this registry settings for NLS_LANG
- Columns should be VARCHAR2
- Connection string should include `OLEDB.NET=True` 
  for further reference see http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28431/using.htm#i1017221

Other points to check could be OS and Client and OLEDB versions... some have bugs or strange behaviour...

Answer (score 1):

Is your datatype and parameter type nvarchar2?